# Can we disable parameter with respect to another parameter in cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Is there any way by which we can disable certain parameters if a user enters a certain value in preceding parameters. For example

```
    dbUseExisitngParamGroup:
        Type: String
        Description: Enable or disable custom DB Parameter Group
        Default: 'false'
        AllowedValues:
          - true
          - false      
    dbExisitngParamGroupName:
        Type: String
        Description: Name of custom DB Parameter Group that you want for this RDS.
    dbNewParamsGroupFamilyName:
        Type: String
        Description: Set this value if to a valid param family if you want to create a new ParamGroup for this DB.
        Default: 'aurora5.6'
```

If I enter false in "dbUseExisitngParamGroup" parameter then "dbExisitngParamGroupName" parameter should gets disable for the user to enter any value

Comment: Thats the only answer? Is there still no way to disable the input box?

Answer (score 1):

No.

But you can  add conditions to your resources so that if `dbUseExisitngParamGroup` is supplied, `dbExisitngParamGroupName` is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Asdfg's answer with a little more detail: Use a condition. You can define a condition in the Conditions section of your template like this (I'm using JSON because I'm more familiar with it than YAML):

```
"dbCreateNewParamGroupCondition": {
    "Fn::Equals": [
        {
            "Ref": "dbExistingParamGroupName"
        },
        ""
    ]
}
```

Then in your resource you would use the Conditions logical ID (`dbCreateNewParamGroupCondition`). The resource will only be created if the condition evaluates to true:

```
{
    "Type": "AWS::SomeResource::Type",
    "Condition": "dbCreateNewParamGroupCondition"
    ...
}
```

Comment: Is this the only way?